# Why do changes to one EditText change all EditText with same id?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Why do changes to one EditText change all EditText with same id despite being stored and changed individually?

**Example:**

I'm trying to create a table of **n** rows. Each row is created from `table_row.xml` a layout file containing an EditText with an `android:id="@+id/row_value"`

When I call `updateTable()` all EditText in the table are changed to the value of the last change.

- Given: **n**=3,
- The user enters a, b, c in each EditText respectively
- `updateTable()` is called and
  all EditText values are set to c (**the last value**)

**table_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/row_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</TableRow>
```

**Fragment.java**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) base.findViewById(R.id.data_table);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        TableRow row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);
        EditText inputField = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.row_value);
        final int index = i;
        inputField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                EditText editText = (EditText)v;
                String value = editText.getText().toString();
                storage.put(index, value); // Store row number and user value;
            }
        }
        editTextMap.put(index, inputField);// Store a reference to editText
        table.addView(row);
    }
    updateTable();
    return table;
}

private void updateTable(){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String value = storage.get(i);
        EditText edit = editTextMap.get(i);
        edit.setText(value);
        edit.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `inputField` in your `updateTable`?

Comment: And what is `i` in your `OnFocusChangeListener`? It's not valid for it to not be `final` or a field variable.

Comment: Here's the part where I say it works for me. Have you tried creating a new project with just this code?

Comment: I've built a project with the above and it seems to work. So there must be a quirk with my current implementation

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `android:id` attribute from the EditText and instead replaced it with an `android:tag` attribute instead.

So Instead of:

```
EditText inputField = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.row_value);
```

Changed to:

```
EditText inputField = (EditText) row.findViewWithTag("userInput");
```

`UpdateTable()` Now works correctly in that each EditText value is restored to it's proper value instead of being restored to the last entry.

I'm not entirely satisfied with this solution.

Answer (score -1):

The ids of your components MUST be unique, if some components have the same id when you getViewById you will get more than one and if you change the text of what you got all edittexts will be modified